# Move from Kendo Grid ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Kendo Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

Since i am totally new to Kendo UI, I just downloaded a Kendo UI MVC working sample, from a YouTube Tutorial link. I modified it to suit my requirement. However, it uses Entity Framework. I now have a need to develop a Kendo Grid without using Entity Framework. So i want to migrate it to regular Kendo UI Grid.  It is using Razor syntax in the Index , refers to the Control class methods which return JSON. Generally speaking what would be the changes i need to make ? Or alternately where can i find working samples which use the plain Kendo UI Grid (not MVC) ?

Edit:- Maybe i should study these. https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net

Comment: By plain kendo grid, do you mean just the client API?  Or still using the server-side wrappers?

Comment: do you mean by not MVC as JS for example?

Comment: @BrianMains I want to avoid using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC Wrappers (i suppose that is server side wrappers). I just want to refer to a Webmethod in code behind which returns JSON which i bind to the Grid.

Comment: @mah I want to use Kendo Grid UI with the JS part, but not the MVC wrapper.

Comment: @Chakra check this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/data-binding